# WPF and Powershell - Handling events

Tags: wpf, powershell, wpf-controls

Can anyone point me in the right direction for some documentation about handling WPF UI events in Powershell?

I want to know how to, for example, call a function when a CheckBox or Radio Button is changed.

Cheers!

Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering WPF and PowerShell, have a look at [WPF Linkcollection for PowerShell](http://pauerschell.blogspot.com/2010/04/wpf-linkcollection-for-powershell.html) from Bernd. You will find many interesting links that will help you.

Considering your problem, just use pattern

```powershell
$control.Add_<someevent>({ what to do })
```

For example, `someevent` could be [`Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) for a Button:

```powershell
$button.Add_Click({ $global:clicked = $true })
```

You pass in a scriptblock that handles the event.

Comment: How do you get at the event args and/or sender arguments.

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party (by over 4 years). Specifically addressing [jpierson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83658/jpierson)'s comment.

But in case anyone finds this post, as I did, via Googling PowerShell WPF event handling, wanting to obtain the Sender control (sender) & Event Args (e), here's how...

**C# version (non-specific template)**

```
private void Handler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
  //do something with sender and/or e...
}
```

**PowerShell version**

```
$WPFControl.Add_Handler({
  $sender = $args[0]
  $e      = $args[1]
  #do something with sender and/or e...
})
```

And onto a specific MouseWheelHandler event handler

**C# version** (where the MouseWheelHandler event has been bound to a control)

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  ScrollViewer scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
  //do something with sender and/or e...
}
```

**PowerShell version**

```
$ScrollViewer.Add_PreviewMouseWheel({
  $sender = [System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer]$args[0]
  $e      = [System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs]$args[1]
  #do something with sender and/or e...
})
```

In PowerShell, to ***get the types of sender and event args***, use the following

```
$ScrollViewer.Add_PreviewMouseWheel({
  Write-Host $args[0]
  Write-Host $args[1]
})
```

which (in the above example) will give you...

```
System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer
System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs
```

Comment: I've serached for a 3 weeks on SO and Microsoft forums, and no one is able to give me an answer on simple quesion, how to work with events in PowerShell, and as I assumed it's really easy. Thx a lot, you never late to the party ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok, it's a long shot because this post is from 2015, but i tried and it's not working for me.
It doesn't rise an error but i don't have access to sender properties

```
Get-Variable -Name Ctrl_* -ValueOnly | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^btn_[^_]+_Nav_(Previous|Next)$'} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Add_Click({
        $sender = [System.Windows.Controls.Button]$args[0]
        $sender.Name
    })
}
```

I try to make a generic navigation system for an hmi

Best Regards,
Richard