# WPF/PowerShell, copy single cell from a datagrid without header

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

In a WPF DataGrid via PowerShell, I would like the user to be able to copy the cells as follows: 1) if multiple cells and rows are selected selected then copy it with header. 2) If only a single cell is selected copy the cell content without the header. In the sample shown below, I've set ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" which enables to copy the selected cells/rows with header which satisfies first requirement indicated above. However, I'm looking for some ideas or quick samples for the second requirement shown above, that is to copy the content without header if only single cell is selected (from context menu or shortcut). I had tried mouse events but couldn't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
[xml]$xaml=@"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="425" Width="550">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb_Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149"/>
    <Button x:Name="bt_Search" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" IsDefault="True" Height="22" Margin="165,10,0,0" />        
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Margin="10,45,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="100" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ColumnWidth="Auto" AlternationCount="1" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" Background="White" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"> 
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" Header="Copy With Header"/>                                
                <MenuItem Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Save}" Header="Save"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>  
</Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

#Turn XAML into PowerShell objects
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'x:Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

#sample data
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$Table = $DataSet.Tables.Add("Table")
$Properties = @("Country","Capital","Population")
$Properties | foreach {
 $Column = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn($_)
 $Table.Columns.Add($Column)
 }
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("China PR","Beijing","20,693,000")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("India","New Delhi","16,787,949") 
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Japan","Tokyo","13,189,000")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Philippines","Manila","12,877,253")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Russia","Moscow","11,541,000")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Egypt","Cairo","10,230,350")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("USA","Washington, D.C","658,893")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("China PR","Beijing","20,693,000")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("India","New Delhi","16,787,949") 
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Japan","Tokyo","13,189,000")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Philippines","Manila","12,877,253")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Russia","Moscow","11,541,000")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("Egypt","Cairo","10,230,350")
$Null=$Table.Rows.Add("USA","Washington, D.C","658,893")

#populate datagrid
$DataView = New-Object System.Data.DataView($Table)
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[void] $array.AddRange($DataView)       
$dg.clear()
$dg.ItemsSource = $array
$dg.IsReadOnly = $true

$bt_Search.Add_Click({
$SearchValue = $tb_Search.text
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dg.Items.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($dg.Items[$i].Row[$dg.Columns.DisplayIndex] -eq "$SearchValue")
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Keyword Found")
        $dg.ScrollIntoView($dg.Items[$i]) #scroll to the row that contains the keyword searched
    }
}
})

#Display Form
$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically set the `ClipboardCopyMode` in the CanExcecute method of the `ApplicationCommands.Copy` command. This is how you would do this in C#:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    dataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count == 1 ? 
        DataGridClipboardCopyMode.ExcludeHeader : DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ... SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
    <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8, for the suggestion. I receive following exception when trying CommandBinding in above sample script. Any thoughts/suggestion around as to why this exception could occur?
       >> "Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to create a 'CanExecute' from the text 'CommandBinding_CanExecute'."

Comment: @user5349170: In Powershell, you need to hook up the event handler just like you did with the `Click` event for the button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413418/wpf-and-powershell-handling-events

Comment: I was able add a event handler to dynamically set the ClipboardCopyMode, it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.